# insert function keeps recreating root node

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to create a non-recursive insert() function. The only example I have in the book is a recursive one and I'm trying to convert it. Just so you have an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish and why I'll include the instructions.

Write a class for implementing a simple binary search tree capable of storing numbers. The class should have member functions:

```
void insert(double x)
bool search(double x)
void inorder(vector <double> & v)
```

The insert function should not use recursion directly or indirectly by calling a recursive function.

There is more, but I think this gives the idea behind what I'm asking about. As of now the function just keep recreating the root node. Here is what I have.

Edit: Adding full code for clarity.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BinaryTree {

private:
struct TreeNode {

    double value;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode(double value1,
        TreeNode *left1 = nullptr,
        TreeNode *right1 = nullptr) {

        value = value1;
        left = left1;
        right = right1;
    }
};

TreeNode *root;    //pointer to the root of the tree
bool search(double x, TreeNode *t) {

    while (t) {
        std::cout << "running through t." << std::endl;
        if (t->value == x) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (x < t->value) {
            std::cout << "wasn't found, moving left." << std::endl;
            search(x, t->left);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "wasn't found, moving right." << std::endl;
            search(x, t->right);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "wasn't found." << std::endl;
    return false;
}


public:

std::vector<TreeNode> v;

BinaryTree() {
    root = nullptr;
}

void insert(double x) {
    TreeNode *tree = root;

    if (!tree) {
        std::cout << "Creating tree." << x << std::endl;
        root = new TreeNode(x);
        return;
    }

    while (tree) {

        std::cout << "Adding next value." << std::endl;
        if (tree->value == x) return;

        if (x < tree->value) {
            tree = tree->left;
            tree->value = x;
        }
        else {
            tree = tree->right;
            tree->value = x;
        }
    }

}
bool search(double x) {

    return search(x, root);
}

/*void inOrder(TreeNode *v) const {

    while (root != nullptr) {

        inOrder(root->left);
        v.push_back(root->value);
        inOrder(root->right);
        v.push_back(root->value);
    }
}*/
};

int main() {

    BinaryTree t;

    std::cout << "Inserting the numbers 5, 8, 3, 12, and 9." << std::endl;
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(8);
    t.insert(3);
    t.insert(12);
    t.insert(9);

    std::cout << "Looking for 12 in tree." << std::endl;
    if (t.search(12)) {
        std::cout << "12 was found." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Here are the numbers in order." << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the root variable defined? is it a member of the class? In the first line of the insert function you use it, but I don't see where it is defined.

Comment: It is defined in the class. If I need to add the rest of the code I will.

Comment: Your code never assigns to `root`. And the only node it allocates is a root node.

Comment: Yes, please add the rest of the code, it might just be obvious once we can see it. Currently we're speculating...

Comment: Okay, I've added the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `insert()` method, you're setting the value of every node you pass to the new value. That's probably not what you intended.

If you want to insert it, you need to figure out where it goes, create a new node with the appropriate value, and insert the new node into the tree, being careful to handle the nodes that were there previously.